# How do you filter based on URL instead of IP address? (Swift Network Extensions)

Tags: swift, networking, networkextension

I'm trying to make a content blocker for MacOS with Apple Network Extensions.
I have set everything up correctly, but it seems like I can only filter on IP address and not URL.
Update: On non-webkit browsers. I.e. Safari Yes. Brave Browser no.

```
class FilterDataProvider: NEFilterDataProvider {

    override func startFilter(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {        
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
    
    override func stopFilter(with reason: NEProviderStopReason, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
    }
    
    override func handleNewFlow(for flow: NEFilterFlow) -> NEFilterDataVerdict {
        // -> THIS DOESN'T WORK <-
        if let url = flow.url?.absoluteString {
            if url.contains("facebook") {
                return .drop()
            }
        }

        // -> THIS WORKS <-
        if let socketFlow = flow as? NEFilterSocketFlow,
           let remoteEndpoint = socketFlow.remoteEndpoint as? NWHostEndpoint {
            let host = remoteEndpoint.hostname
            
            // these are some IP addresses I found for Reddit
            if ["151.101.193.140", "151.101.65.140", "151.101.129.140", "151.101.1.140"].contains(host) {
                return .drop()
            }
        }
        
        return .allow()
    }
}
```

When I was debugging it seemed like flow.url was always nil, whereas I was able to get the IP address via `let remoteEndpoint = socketFlow.remoteEndpoint as? NWHostEndpoint` every time.

But the url property is probably there for a reason? So it should be not nil sometimes?

I know I have set the System Extension up correctly because if I just `return .drop()` it blocks all websites.

Comment: you could try the same technique as what you have in 
`if let socketFlow = flow as? NEFilterSocketFlow,...`, with `NEFilterBrowserFlow`,  such as:
`if let netFlow = flow as? NEFilterBrowserFlow,...`, and get the `parentURL` from that.

Comment: Unfortunately NEFilterBrowserFlow is only available on iOS
and Mac Catalyst..
@workingdog support Ukraine

Comment: Hi @FredrikSkjelvik, were you able to find a solution for your problem. I'm currently running into the same problem and it seems that flow.url is always nil for requests orginated from non-webkit browser. I'm trying with the AppProxyProvider/PacketTunnelProvider as the alternatives.